# Vuejs - interpolation in dynamic component template & scope

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've been trying to get a dynamic component to work that will allow me to render list items individually based on a provided template.
It seems however, that Vue is interpolating the template in the parents scope and not within the `dynamicComponent` scope.

Simple example:

```
<dynamicComponent 
    v-for="item in listItems" 
    v-bind:input="item" 
    v-bind:is="{template:'<p>{{input.name}}</p>'}"
</dynamicComponent>
```

This fails since `input` is not known in the parents scope.

Is there a way to pass a template dynamically *and* have it reference variables/properties within the components scope?

**Edit: Solution**

Turns out I misunderstood the workings of `v-bind:is` a bit.
It allows you to inline bind/create an anonymous component, not add to/manipulate a referenced component.

The correct solution seems to be:

```
<component
  v-for="item in listItems"
  v-bind:input="item"
  v-bind:is="{template:'<p>{{input.name}}</p>', props:['input']}">
</component>
```

Answer (score 0):

`v-bind` is used for a component name property, as you have it, it's binding to an object. You can register a custom component like:

```
component:{
  name: 'my-component',
  template: '<div>...foo...</div>',
},
data () {
    return {
        currentComponent: 'my-component'
    }
}
```

Then do the following:

```
<dynamicComponent v-bind:is="current-component">..</dynamicComponent>
```

Of course, you can register multiple components as needed and then set the `currentComponent` data property to which ever one you want to render.

Another example:

```
import Component1 from 'component-1'
import Component2 from 'component-2'
import Component3 from 'component-3'

components: {
     'component-1': Component1,
     'component-2': Component2,
     'component-3': Component3
},
data () {
    return {
        current: 'component-1'
    }
},
methods: {
    someAction (componentName) {
          this.current = componentName
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm specifically trying to avoid having to create multiple separate component in this instance and am looking for a way to dynamically generate the component via a passed template. This works fine, I'm just stuck at how to reference passed properties within this dynamic template.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `data` property like: v-bind:is="{template:'<p>{{input.name}}</p>', data () { return { foo: input.name }}}"? Dont know if this works, just throwing ideas out at this point.

Comment: I assume you meant `<p>{{foo}}</p>` in the template then? Yes, I've tried that to no avail though, it's the same problem, `foo` does not exists within the parents scope and therefore the interpolation fails since the template is evaluated within the parents scope, not the child component...

Comment: Hmm, what about using a scoped slot? That's about all I can come up with. Is there a particular reason you're creating the component this way and not within the parent or single file?

Comment: Turns out I misunderstood `v-bind:is` a bit. Figured it out now and added the solution / explanation above. Thanks for you help though!

Comment: That makes sense now that I see it. Almost too obvious, good info to know anyhow.